# FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR) Call to a member function replies() on null

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

When I'm trying to update post it's updated successfully but, when it returns it shows error here-

NB: Replies under this post where I'm trying to update.

```
public function show($slug)
{
    $discussion = Discussion::where('slug', $slug)->first();

    $best_answer = $discussion->replies()->where('best_answer', 1)->first();

    return view('discussions.show')
                    ->with('d', $discussion)
                    ->with('best_answer', $best_answer);
}
```

Edit and Update

```
public function edit($slug)
{
    return view('discussions.edit', ['discussion'=> Discussion::where('slug', $slug)->first()]);
}

public function update($id)
{
    $this->validate(request(),[
        'title' => 'required',
        'content' => 'required'
    ]);

    $d = Discussion::find($id);

    $d->title = request()->title;
    $d->content = request()->content;

    $d->save();

    Session::flash('success', 'Discussion updated');

    return redirect()->route('discussion', ['slug', $d->slug]);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a relation `public function replies()` in your `Discussion` model? Oh wait, "_on null_". You can `dd($discussion)` after `$discussion = Discussion::where('slug', $slug)->first();` to see if you actually got any Discussion with that slug

Comment: after dd($discussion); it shows up- 'null'. @kerbholz

Comment: So, there is no `Discussion` with that given slug. Use `dd($slug)` to print out the slug and make sure there's `Discussion` available with that slug in your database. Also make sure your routes are correct, the route for editing seems to work, if I got that right?!

Comment: Hi, @kerbholz thanks for the response. I got that error. It was a silly mistake in the update- return redirect()->route('discussion', ['slug', $d->slug]);  it should be- return redirect()->route('discussion', ['slug'=> $d->slug]);

Comment: So it works now? Nice